# Alternative to capture user raw text input that doesn't invoke Cpython

Tags: python, input, jupyter, ipython, stdout

I'm running input() in a Jupyter Lab notebook on Windows in a Conda environment. The cell in its simplest form I used to debug is like this:

```
%%capture
str = input("Input please:")
```

It responds with Input please: Toes if I input the word Toes. This seems to be because input() invokes Cpython with its call and this can't be captured by %capture as it goes over Jupyter's head, so to speak.

Are there ways to get user raw text input in an embedded Jupyter Notebook that DOES direct to stdout, so it can be redirected or discarded?

Comment: `%%capture` doesn't capture every type of output. In particular, C-level stuff isn't handled that way. And what `input()` makes to present the prompt seems to not be in the channels involved.  But you seem to be making an [X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? It seems you thought you could handle with `%%capture` are now encountering its limitations. But what is the actual goal? Also keep in mind, `input()` is a rudimentary feature meant for working in a text-based console. It is not meant for making a nice user interface. ...

Comment: <continued> Plus you aren't providing what else you are doing. The whole section "It expects a string format of a newick file to convert, which I give it and it works.  ....  because Newick files are not exactly print-pretty", should either have code accompanying it or be left out. We cannot help you on that aspect if you don't provide the related input and actual code that triggers the echo. In short your provided code block isn't doing what your title says.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Wayne The other things it's doing don't really matter. If I run input() and I type Toes I don't want it to print Toes. I'll edit it to ignore the context I was running it in.

Comment: Your comment about C seems to be the root of the problem. The input() docs say it runs an auditing event with the result which invokes Cpython. I did some digging on this repository and wasn't able to find anything about quieting input() so I may need to amend the question to reflect a broader question.

Comment: I was getting at the C-type stuff because often you can user [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) to block commands that make C-type output when you run them in the shell, but that doesn't seem to work for `input()`. You can use ipywidgets to enter text, see [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#string-widgets). That's the modern notebook way to collect input from a user.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you kindly, I see that the question I was asking wasn't quite right due to inexperience. For what it's worth if people want to answer this in future, would it be worth answering? I've seen other people fall afoul of input() while I was looking for answers.

Comment: I don't see away to suppress how it works. It isn't getting treated like code run output or even use of an exclamation to run a shell command. So if you leave it maybe someone else will chime in here with the answer about `input()`.